# Can I specify a name folder in uploading a file in admin in django

Tags: django

Lets say I have:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class Design(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="background/")
```

I want that my location file to have the same name as the class Book name.

So for example i have a book named HP, i want to have a folder HP/background.

Someone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a callable to accomplish this.

Django describes this in the documentation: [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

So you can describe your model class using the callable iso harcoded value:

```
class Design(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_path)
```

The callable itself will be passed 2 arguments.
First argument "*instance*" represents the model instance.
If your "*Design*" model somehow refers to your "*Book*" model you may fetch the required data in order to construct the path.